# Looking for counter-example: If $f_j$ → $f$ uniformly on a domain S, does it follow that the functions $1/f_j$ converge uniformly to $1/f$ on S?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Also, they never vanish.

I know this is not true since both $f_j$ and $f$ must be bounded below by some constant C.

But I couldn't find a counter-example for it.
Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: I point out they never vanish, meaning both $f_j$ and $f$ won't be zero.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [If $f_j$ converges uniformly to $f$, does $\frac{1}{f_j}$ converge uniformly to $\frac{1}{f}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1134653/if-f-j-converges-uniformly-to-f-does-frac1f-j-converge-uniformly-to)

Comment: Not quite. What I need is a counter-example. Thanks though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $S=[1, \infty[$ and 
$$f_j(x)=\begin{cases}\frac1{x}&1\leq x<j\\\frac1{j}&x\geq j\end{cases}$$
Then $f_j$ converge uniformly to $f(x)=\frac1{x}$

But $\frac1{f_j} \to \frac1{f}$, but not uniformly.

For every $\epsilon>0$, for every $j$, if we take $x = j+2\epsilon$
$$\left|\frac1{f_j(j+2\epsilon)} - \frac1{f(j+2\epsilon)}\right| = \left|j-(j+2\epsilon)\right| = 2\epsilon > \epsilon$$
The convergence is not uniform.

---

After posting my answer, I thought of an easier example. Let $S = \mathbb{R}$ and 
$$f_j(x) = \frac1j$$
The constant fonction. Then $f_j$ converge uniformly to $f(x) = 0$ but 
$$\frac1{f_j(x)} = \frac1{\tfrac1j} = j$$
and $\frac1{f_j}$ doesn't converge!